# window.location, problems with page layout, css

Tags: php, redirect, layout, offset

I'm trying to use window.loaction.replace() and discovered unwanted behavior.

The redirect works fine but it messes up my html structure.

It redirects to the wanted site but the top panel becomes a ghost. As far as I can tell the body structure behaves like it has a "negative margin the size of the panelheight". If I double the size of the panel with firebug it comes down.

The whole page looks like there is no panel at all after redirecting.

```
  redirector: function(e){
   window.location.replace(e);
  }
```

The top panel is a nav element containing to ul's from which the right one is floated right. It is not fixed:

```
.panel{
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9998;
}
```

Even after manually reloading the page the bug doesn't disappear.

EDIT:

Same problem occurs if i redirect with PHP header: location...

The complete html,body moves up.

If I had to describe this bug in css it would look like:

```
html{
height:100%
position: absolute;
top:-40px;
bottom:40px;
}
```

Comment: While there have been bugs related to location.replace, they are history related and wouldn't affect the layout, because it is essentially a full reload.  Chances are it is casued by coding error.  Do you have a fiddle or test page that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi. It doesn't matter if I use JS or a PHP redirect. If I klick links everything is Ok. But if I submit a form via POST and redirect then I get this bug. There is no output before the headers. I couldn't provide a jsfiddle since it looks like something is wrong on the server side but I have no clue what.

Comment: See the edited question. The html,body shifts upwards by the height of the top panel. Outside of the "viewport". An offset bug..

Comment: Well, if the problem persists even after reload, you can try to fiddle the html (+css+js) code after the problem happened.  Perhaps the server will do something based on session/database that affected the layout?

Comment: I found the problem. I need to figure out why but if I delete my footer everything is fine. There seems to be a calculation problem. Panel+Contentwrapper = 100% height of the body,html. The footer rest beyond the contenwrapper and is not within the calculated 100%. So the size becomes 100% plus pagefooter. This expands the HTML,BODY and leads to the bug.

Comment: Any explanation why this happens only after a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's useful for someone else:

The problem occurs if the calculated height of the content inside the body,html tags is higher than the body,html itself.

If the html,body have 100% height and inside the body are for example three elements:

Top Navigation Panel
Content Wrapper
Footer

And the calculated CSS height for these three element is higher than the body height it leads to this problem.

I don't know why it does only show up after a redirect but not if I navigate through links.

Comment: Glad that you are on the way to solve the problem.  Have you tried to run the result html through validators?  They are useful at detecting structural problems, which can cauese layout to become weird.